# TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'

Tags: python

This is my code -

```
import random
symbols=["+","-","x"]
question=0
score=0
choice=0
name=input("What is your name?")
while question<10:
    r1=random.randint(1,10)
    r2=random.randint(1,10)
    s1=random.choice(symbols)
    add=(r1+r2)
    sub=(r1-r2)
    times=(r1*r2)
    print("What is ",+str(r1),+s1,+str(r2),)
    ask=int(input())
    if s1=="+":
        if ask==add:
            print("Correct")
            score=score+1
        else:
            print("Incorrect")
    if s1=="-":
        if ask==sub:
            print("Correct")
            score=score+1
        else:
            print("Incorrect")
    if s1=="x":
        if ask==sub:
            print("Correct")
            score=score+1
        else:
            print("Incorrect")
print("Your score is: "+score,"out of 10")
```

and the error I get is -

```
    What is your name?Emma
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Emma/Documents/Python/Questions Maths.py", line 14, in <module>
        print("What is ",+str(r1),+s1,+str(r2),)
    TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

Comment: Don't mix commas in your print statement and you should be fine.

Comment: Okay, so what is your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bad operand type for unary +: 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591385/bad-operand-type-for-unary-str)

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove commas :

```
print("What is " +str(r1)+s1+str(r2))
print("What is", r1, s1, r2)
```

Also in the last line :

```
print("Your score is: " + score + "out of 10")
```

But as a more pythonic way you can use `%` or `format` :

```
print("What is {0}{1}{2}".format(r1,s1,r2))
```

OR :

```
print("What is %d%s%d" % (r1,s1,r2))
```

Comment: Also the last line will need to have a comma removed and a plus inserted.

Comment: @BlackVegetable yes , thansk , i add it to answer

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the line:

```
print("What is ",+str(r1),+s1,+str(r2),)
```

for this 2 options

1. `print("What is "+ str(r1) + s1 + str(r2))`
2. `print("What is %d %s %d" % (r1,s1,r2 ))`
3. `print("What is", r1, s1, r2)`

   - `%s` for string
   - `%d` for integer
   - `%f.2` for float

And you will need to change also your last line:

```
print("Your score is: "+score,"out of 10")
```

for:

1. `print("Your score is: "+ score +" out of 10")`
2. `print("Your score is: %s out of 10" % score)`
3. `print("Your score is:", score, "out of 10")`