# Python TypeError: Bad operand type for unary +: 'str'

Tags: python

I tried running a block of code and got the above error for this line of code:

```
print("Congratulations! You swapped out a", box3, "for", + str( randomPersuade2 ) + " Dollars. Enjoy!")
```

box3 holds a value from a list of items

```
box1,box2,box3,box4, box5 = ["Car", "TV", "DVD", "Overseas Holiday", "Box of chocolates"]
```

randomPersuade2 is a variable that holds a value from a random.randint() funct.

```
randomPersuade2 = random.randint(200,5000)
```

As mentioned in the title, I get the error

TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'

How would I resolve this? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why is there a `+` before the `str()` call?

Comment: Remove the plus or the comma

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bad operand type for unary +: 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591385/bad-operand-type-for-unary-str)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part is problematic : You have a comma AND a plus sign. You need to get rid of one of them.

```
box3, "for", + str(randomPersuade2)
```

#### Explaning the error

Here, Python thinks you want to use the "unary" `+` operator.

This operator is not the same as the one is `num_a + num_b`. You use it like this : `+num`.

And it just.. doesn't change the value of a number. Yeah not really useful. But here, you have a `str` object, which is not a number. The object on which the operator is called is an "operand".

So here you go : "Bad operand type for unary +: 'str'".

Comment: Thanks, I just realized I had a comma leftover from when I was messing about earlier, thanks for bringing it up

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 variables that you want to use in print message. A clean way to do it is:

```
print('Congratulations! You swapped out a, {}, for, {}  Dollars. 
       Enjoy!'.format(var1,var2))
```

Answer (score 0):

, operator automatic add space after string so remove + sign after , operator:

```
print("Congratulations! You swapped out a", box3, "for", str( randomPersuade2 ) + " Dollars. Enjoy!")
```