# Python: String Concatenation TypeError - bad operand type for unary +: 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, concatenation

I'm writing a simple function to determine wind direction/speed. Using the darksky web API. Trying to print a sentence that includes two variables, speed and direction.

I have tried making the windspeed / direction vars ints, floats, or strs.

```
weather = forecast('api_key',lat, -long)
windbearing = weather.windBearing
windspeed = float(weather.windSpeed)

def windcompass(windbearing):
    val = int((windbearing/22.5)+.5)
    argument = ["N","NNE","NE","ENE","E","ESE", "SE", "SSE","S","SSW","SW","WSW","W","WNW","NW","NNW"]
    return argument[(val % 16)]

direction = windcompass(windbearing)

print('The wind is blowing ', + windspeed, + 'at ', + direction, + 'MPH')
```

I am getting this **error**:

> TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'

Comment: `print('The wind is blowing ' + windspeed + 'at ' + direction + 'MPH')`. You do not need the commas in between your `+` operations. But I would highly suggest some sort of [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/)

Comment: `print('The wind is blowing ', + windspeed, + 'at ', + direction, + 'MPH')` - if you look closely, you're confusing two things: string concatenation AND multiple parameters passed to `print`. Either remove commas or pluses.

Comment: @Buckeye `windspeed` is a float, so that's still going to fail. OP probably wants commas, not pluses.

Comment: @wjandrea OP just needs to make them strings. Simple as that. no need to have commas between the + operations and no the sentence makes no sense with commas everywhere

Comment: @Buckeye I'm not sure what you mean. I'm talking about `print('The wind is blowing', windspeed, 'at', direction, 'MPH')`

Comment: I think you have `windspeed` and `direction` reversed

Comment: @wjandrea `+` can be used after converting ints/floats to str. You might wanna check my answer

Comment: @wjandrea I'm fairly certain OP wants to create a string and print it as opposed to just using print(str1, str2) to have them on one line. Probably testing the string to return it somewhere as a value. But hey I am not the author

Comment: @Buckeye I'm really confused. Does this not accomplish what you're describing? `print('The wind is blowing', windspeed, 'at', direction, 'MPH')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bad operand type for unary +: 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591385/bad-operand-type-for-unary-str)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not using commas solves your issue, I'd suggest you use str.format or f strings since you will not have to cast floats/ints into strs.

- `print('The wind is blowing {} at {} MPH.'.format(direction, windspeed))` (py2 and py3)
- `print(f'The wind is blowing {direction} at {windspeed} MPH.')` (py3 only)

If your code is going to run in python3 environments only, using f strings is the cleanest and the fastest (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722105/format-strings-vs-concatenation#answer-38722192)) solution. However, if your code has to be polyglot, I'd suggest using str.format as it is way cleaner than string concatenation IMO.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use commas** in print function:

```
print( str1 + str2 + ...)
```

And you probably want to **convert `ints`/`floats` to `str`** first:

```
print(str(float_value) + str(int_value) + ...)
```

Example (your code):

```
print('The wind is blowing ' + str(windspeed) + ' at ' + str(direction) + ' MPH')
```

Comment: *"Don't use commas in print statement"*? Why not? `print` takes multiple arguments, which it convert to `str` and separate with spaces (by default).

Comment: Minor thing, `print` is a function in Python 3, not a statement

Comment: Using commas is not one of the methods I use. Because I also use other functions like `end` so it gets mixed.

Comment: @wjandrea It's not that minor at all; there is a big difference between the two aside from the fact that parentheses are (somewhat) optional with the statement. (I say "somewhat", because there is a very big difference between `print a, b` and `print(a, b)`; one prints two strings separate by a space; the other prints a tuple.)

Comment: @BlackThunder That's what I'm asking: why not use commas? and what is `end()`?

Comment: @wjandrea Sorry, I mistyped. I meant parameter. `print(..., end = "...")`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, I downvoted cause *"Don't use commas in print function"* is bad advice. IMO the easiest method uses commas, like I wrote in my answer. **But** I'm open to your opinion.

Comment: Thanks! Knew it was something stupid. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the pluses and the extra whitespace:

```
print('The wind is blowing', windspeed, 'at', direction, 'MPH')
```

`print` converts each argument to a string, so you don't need to do `str(windspeed)`. And it separates the arguments with spaces.